# How to assign the entire 2d or 1d vector a particular value?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

For example:

I want to assign the entire `char a[n][m]` (or a 2d vector) using `operator=`.

The for loop way is kind of place-taking. I wonder about a function that can do it in a line.
Just like we are able to assign 0 to the entire array: `int a[n][m]={0}`.

Comment: Yes, I got fill() there. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to initialize a whole 2D array with values of your own? E.g. something like this?  array<int, 2, 3> arr{ {{0,1}, {2,3}, {4,5}} }; or just the single value mentioned above?